# Populate hash with array keys and default value

Tags: ruby, hash

Stuck on a Code Wars Challenge: Complete the solution so that it takes an array of keys and a default value and returns a hash with all keys set to the default value.

My answer results in a parse error:

```
def solution([:keys, :default_value])
  return { :keys => " ", :default_value => " " }
end
```

Am I missing something to do with returning a hash key with *all* the keys set to the default value?

Comment: While I prefer Arup's solution, the "initialize a collection-add to it-return it" pattern is handled by `Enumerable#inject` in Ruby: `keys.inject({}) { |h, k| h.merge({k => default_val}) }` or `keys.inject({}) { |h, k| h[k] = default_val ; h }`.

Comment: @Michael, to get rid of that unsightly `h` at the end of the block: `keys.each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = default_val }`.

Comment: To replace it with an unsightly method name? I'd rather not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do as below :

```
def solution(keys,default_val)
  Hash[keys.product([default_val])]
end

solution([:key1,:key2],12)  # => {:key1=>12, :key2=>12}
```

Read [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [`Kernel#Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash).

Comment: Thanks. So using `Hash` before an array turns that array into a Hash? Can you give me a real world example of where the `product` method could be used - i mean, why would the same value be assigned to multiple keys? Is there another method i could have used other than product?

Comment: @Abraham yes... then do `Hash[keys.zip([default_val]* keys.size)]`.. But in this case it is not idiomatic.. so I use `Array#product`.

Comment: @Abraham For example: you have hash that contain number of letters of in a sentence ( {:a => 0, :b => 0...} ) and you count each letter, using `each_char` for example, you can do this `hash1[:a] += 1`. Without default value you have to check if hash contain key, if yes you can `hash[:a]+=1`, if not you must assign it via `hash[:a] = 1`. ps. `[]#*` is *interesting* - it can take string as an argument while `[]#product` will raise TypeError. `[1,2,3].* '3'
#=> "13233"`. You forgot to change 3 to Numeric, and you have string instead of array.

Comment: This forgets to dup the default value when possible, though.

Comment: @Denis Is your advice for me ?

Comment: I looked up all the methods put forwards by all of you and i understand them all but i've found a less complicated answer and added it to my question - does it achieve the same outcome?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: mostly for OP, if he ever needs to use that with e.g. strings and subsequently modifies them in place.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise amending your solution to this:

```
def solution(keys, default_value)
  hash = {}
  keys.each do |key|
    value = default_value.dup rescue default_value
    hash[key] = value
  end
  hash
end
```

The `dup` is to work around the nasty case where default_value is a string and you then do e.g.:

```
hash[:foo] << 'bar'
```

… with your version, this would modify multiple values in place instead of a single one.

Comment: Denis, I am sure you are aware that you could have written `keys.each_with_object({}) do |key, hash|` to get rid of `hash = {}` and `hash` at the end, but chose to do it this way.  I'd be interested in your views on the stylistic difference.

Comment: I was merely fixing OP's function. Code I'd write myself would be more like `Hash[keys.map{ |k| [k, val] }`.